# Excel VBA Object Not Released as Expected When Using .NET 3.5 Hashtable

Tags: excel, vba, .net-3.5

When I call the `Add` method of an instance of a .NET 3.5 `System.Collections.Hashtable` to add an instance of a VBA class, I cannot subsequently get the `Hashtable` to release the instance of the VBA class.

Here is my minimal VBA class (named `TestObject`):

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Debug.Print "Initialize"
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Debug.Print "Terminate"
End Sub
```

Here is the Module that instantiates the class and then releases the instance of the class.  No `Hashtable` yet...

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()
    Dim oTestObject As TestObject
    Dim oTestObject2 As TestObject
    
    Set oTestObject = New TestObject
    Set oTestObject2 = oTestObject
    
    Set oTestObject = Nothing
    Set oTestObject2 = Nothing
End Sub
```

Note I am creating two references to the object and releasing it twice.  When the object is instantiated, the Immediate window displays this:

```
Initialize
```

Upon executing the last line (i.e. having released both references to the object), I see

```
Terminate
```

added to the Immediate windows.

So far, so good...

But when I run the following code, I never see `Terminate` appear in the Immediate window:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()
    Dim oTestObject As TestObject
    Dim oTestObject2 As TestObject
    Dim ht As Hashtable
    
    Set oTestObject = New TestObject
    Set oTestObject2 = oTestObject

    Set ht = New Hashtable
    ht.Add "key", oTestObject
    
    Set oTestObject = Nothing
    Set oTestObject2 = Nothing
    
    ht.Clear
    Set ht = Nothing
End Sub
```

This appears to be a memory leak.  How do I get the `Hashtable` to release its reference to the object it is holding?

UPDATE:

As I stated in a comment, the instance of `TestObject` is also not released when using a `SortedList`.  For me, this turns out to be a bigger problem, as `Dictionary` is a well behaved substitute for `Hashtable`, but I can't find a replacement for `SortedList`:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()
    Dim oTestObject As TestObject
    Dim oTestObject2 As TestObject
    Dim sl As SortedList
    
    Set oTestObject = New TestObject
    Set oTestObject2 = oTestObject
    Set sl = New SortedList
    
    sl.Add "key", oTestObject
    
    Set oTestObject = Nothing
    Set oTestObject2 = Nothing
    sl.Clear
    Set sl = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: I guess the Hashtable holds a reference to the class so its's not really terminated. Try to explicitly set each object in the hashtable to nothing before clearing it to see it that helps. But I have to ask, why a hashtable and not a Dictionary? They should function the same.

Comment: @KostasK. just did some tests myself out of curiosity and seems like your suggestion (setting each object in the hashtable to nothing) doesn't work neither. Just can confirm the issue but without solution.

Comment: Switching to a `Dictionary` object from the Microsoft Scripting Runtime library instead of the `Hashtable` object from the .NET 3.5 library does solve the problem in the specific example I gave.   Similarly the `Collection` object (not sure what library this comes from) also properly releases objects when references to it are set to `Nothing` (there is no `Clear` or `RemoveAll` method).  However, the problem I stated also occurs when using `SortedList` from the .NET 3.5 library, and as far as I know, there is no well behaving substitute for this.